# How can I edit ASP.Net MVC C# project template files in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

I would like to add some additional folders to the defaults that are created when I use the ASP.Net MVC template to start the website/web application.

Specifically I want to add a "ViewModels" folder. Where are these templates located? 
I've looked in

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates\CSharp\Web
```

But don't see any templates there.

Comment: There are [instruction here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185319.aspx).

Comment: Followed the instructions but the new templates do not show up anywhere with in the "new project" dialog. I've checked the box to add the template to VS and even restarted VS but no joy.

Comment: It might show up under the `Templates > Visual C#` root instead of under `Templates > Visual C# > Web`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please look at the path

```
Install Directory\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Web\MVC\CodeTemplates\
```